# How to reduce sleep method in the entire python script

Tags: python, selenium

The script is like below

```
def ApplicationLogin(request):
    login = excel.get_cell_value(constants.file_path, 'Login', 0, 'Username')
    password = excel.get_cell_value(constants.file_path, 'Login', 0, 'Password')


    login = get_login_page(request.node.driver)

    login.enter_NTlogin(login)
    login.enter_password(password)

    sleep(3)

    obj = get_dashboard_page(request.node.driver)

    obj.click_on_dropdown()
    sleep(3)   

    obj.click_on_method1()
    sleep(3)

    obj.click_on_method2()
    sleep(3)

    obj.select_method3()
    sleep(3)

    obj.select_method4()
    sleep(3)

    obj.click_on_method5()
    sleep(3)   

    obj.click_on_method6()
    sleep(3)

    obj.select_method7()
    sleep(3)

    obj.select_method8()
    sleep(3)

    obj.click_on_method9()
    sleep(3)   


    obj.click_on_method10()
    sleep(3)

    obj.click_on_Logout()
    sleep(3)

    request.node.driver.close()
```

Please let me know how i can reduce sleep method in the entire script instead of  using multiple times

Comment: Have a look at [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after each function call you need to sleep for some time.

```
obj.click_on_dropdown()
sleep(2)   

obj.click_on_method1()
sleep(3)
```

And this time isn't consistent. If you can accomodate constant wait time, you can improve your code. Then, you can try what @[Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168011/guy) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

```
def run_and_sleep(function, sleep_time=2):
    function()
    sleep(sleep_time)

def ApplicationLogin(request):
    login = excel.get_cell_value(constants.file_path, 'Login', 0, 'Username')
    password = excel.get_cell_value(constants.file_path, 'Login', 0, 'Password')

    run_and_sleep(obj.click_on_dropdown)
    run_and_sleep(obj.click_on_method1, sleep_time=3)
    run_and_sleep(obj.click_on_method2)
    run_and_sleep(obj.select_method3)
    run_and_sleep(obj.select_method4)
    run_and_sleep(obj.click_on_method5, sleep_time=5)
    run_and_sleep(obj.click_on_method6)
    ...
```